# Is it safe to make groups/families sit apart from each other?

Tags: safety, family

Some air companies allow you to select a seat for additional fee.
Some go further and intentionally chose different seats for passengers travelling together.

Consider now travelling woman with her 12-13 y.o. child. What will be her behavior in case of emergency evacuation? Will she go to the nearest emergency exit or to her child? I think she will most likely do the last. And this behavior can be really dangerous to other passengers.

So, is it regulated somehow?

Comment: As far as I know, there is a policy only for infants and seniors, as to in need passenger, not to fly on emergency rows.

Comment: @Simon Well, you are mistaken. [AC Pobeda](http://www.pobeda.aero/en)  does exactly this. It shuffles the passengers intentionally making them pay for sitting together.

Comment: Spirit also does this. You have to pay for a particular seat, otherwise it selects your seats randomly. If you buy tickets together and don't pay you will not sit together. (Well, you probably have a 1 in 88 chance of sitting together) It's kind of a pricing game. Their fare is almost always cheapest, so it comes up first on kayak or priceline. But if you want to do simple things like sit next to each other or take a carryon it probably ends up costing more

Comment: _intentionally choose different seats for passengers travelling together_ - do you have proof of this?

Comment: Considering that airlines are concerned about unaccompanied minors, it seems strange to see them separating minors from their relatives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some airline authorities recognise the exact scenario you raise. The UK [CAA](https://www.caa.co.uk/Passengers/On-board/Seating-allocation/) state:

> Young children and infants who are accompanied by adults, should
>   ideally be seated in the same seat row as the adult. Children and
>   accompanying adults should not be separated by more than one aisle.
>   Where this is not possible, children should be separated by no more
>   than one seat row from accompanying adults. **This is because the speed
>   of an emergency evacuation may be affected by adults trying to reach
>   their children.**

The [FAA](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8900.1/V03%20Tech%20Admin/Chapter%2033/03_033_006.htm) state:

> 4)    Passenger Assessment Process for Exit Seating. While the
>   regulation specifically defines the criteria for persons occupying an
>   exit seat, the method by which the airline employee assesses the
>   person assigned to an exit seat should be defined by the air carrier
>   in its company manual. This process generally requires a physical
>   observation of the person and should require additional processes,
>   such as conversation with the person, to determine if he or she meets
>   the selection criteria (the person has the ability to hear,
>   understand, and impart information, and **is not distracted by other
>   responsibilities such as caring for small children or other traveling
>   companions**, etc.).

Airlines may re-seat adults sat in the exit row if they are responsible for children as they understand that the adult may not take their exit row responsibilities above the care for their children.

Update: A [new law](https://www.congress.gov/bill/114th-congress/house-bill/636/text#toc-H8B665C4797E74F00B4D74050D6817986) has just been passed in the US.

**SEC. 2309. Family seating.**

> (a) In general.—Not later than 1 year after the date of enactment of
>   this Act, the Secretary of Transportation shall review and, if
>   appropriate, establish a policy directing all air carriers providing
>   scheduled passenger interstate or intrastate air transportation to
>   establish policies that enable a child, who is age 13 or under on the
>   date an applicable flight is scheduled to occur, to be seated in a
>   seat adjacent to the seat of an accompanying family member over the
>   age of 13, to the maximum extent practicable and at no additional
>   cost, except when assignment to an adjacent seat would require an
>   upgrade to another cabin class or a seat with extra legroom or seat
>   pitch for which additional payment is normally required.

Comment: "The CAA state" - you make it sound like there is only one CAA in the entire world. Might be worth clarifying that you are talking about the UK CAA.

Comment: Nice find! They state this, but is there any regulation or policy that requires airlines to care?

Comment: @ZachLipton FT has various threads on this exact issue, e.g. http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage-pre-consolidation-closed-posting/1175834-unable-sit-exit-row-if-traveling-minor-same-flight-consolidated.html I believe the above statements are taken as policy

Answer (score 6):

There are a few regulations towards passenger seating:

1. All passengers must have a designated seat with a seat belt.
2. Passengers cannot sit on seats designated for crews.
3. Minors, elderly or anyone else deemed unsuitable or unfit (by the cabin crew) cannot be seated in an exit row.

There are no other obligations or regulations or rules that airlines must follow with respect to seating of passengers.

The other rules such as "seats must be upright and tray tables stowed" and that you cannot put carryon luggage on the exit row are towards the safety of the aircraft, and it is enforced even if no one is sitting on the seat.

Therefore, it is perfectly fine for an airline to seat people randomly and charge for preferred seating.  Although airline staff try (for the sake of harmony inside the aircraft and to make the lives of the crews easier) to seat families together, but this cannot be guaranteed.